# How to create images ready to deploy with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How to create images ready to deploy with docker-compose ?

I am a bit confused with **docker-compose**, it feels as a great tool, however, how can I build an image for my service without having a **Dockerfile**?

What I would like to achieve is to create new image from the service declared inside **docker-compose.yml** file. For example, let's say I am having the following setup:

```
api:
  image: node:latest
  volumes:
    - "./api:/"
  ports:
    - "3001:3001"
  command: npm start

client:
  image: node:latest
  volumes:
    - "./client:/"
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  command: npm start

db:
  image: mysql:latest
```

So I am having 2 containers one how do I create ready to push docker image for each of this containers?

For example, I want to deploy `api` container

`$ docker-compose build --no-cache api`

Do I need to run next?

`$ docker build -t api .`

which requires **Dockerfile**, or can I go straight to image push?

And then push it with

`docker push host_name/api:latest`

**1. What is the correct flow ?**

**2. Or maybe this is wrong way completely ?**

### Edit:

What I want to achieve here is to understand or get to know the correct flow for example of situation as I presented in my question where I would like to push this container to actual server. And ofc I do not want to run multicontainer app there. So given this example lets say I have one more container something like **db** (*updated compose file example*). After developing successful applications on my local machine using docker compose I want to **deploy** them lets say AWS where in most cases i have database service and what i need is to upload API container image to EC and I do not want to deploy `db` one or `client` to the same server.

So in order to do that i need to build docker image that i can push to my AWS. How to do that from what I have (docker compose setup) ?

Answer (score 0):

You usually need your image builded before use docker-compose, but there is a buold property to rebuild your iamges directly in compose, anyway you will need a docker file and specify the location:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```